# Открытие и закрытие разных блоков одной кнопкой

Tags: javascript, jquery

Думал есть инфа, но то ли неправильно пишу или что.
Суть задачи такая:
Есть два блока, один скрытый, другой открытый.

```
<a href="#">Кнопка для закрытия и открытия блоков</a>
<div style="display:none; top:0; left:0; min-height:100%">
<ul>Меню</ul>
</div>
<div style="display:block; top:0; left:0; min-height:100%">
<p>инфа </p>
</div>
```

При клике на определенную кнопку закрылся открытый и появился скрытый и наоборот. С плавным эффектом вертикальные блоки, т.е. чтобы налево направо. Как это сделать? и куда копать, помогите пожалуйста

Comment: "С плавным эффектом" -
У jQuery есть метод animate(). Думаю в эту сторону стоит копать:
http://api.jquery.com/animate/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для плавности используйте animate

```js
$(".button_do").click(function() {
    $("#menu, #info").toggle();
});
```

```html
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button class="button_do">Кнопка для закрытия и открытия блоков</button>

<div id="menu" style="display:none;">
  <p>первый блок</p>
</div>

<div id="info">
  <p>второй блок</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Вот:

```js
$(".button_do").click(function() {
  if($("#menu").is("[hidden]")) {
    $("#menu").attr("hidden", false);
    $("#info").attr("hidden", true);
  } else {
    $("#menu").attr("hidden", true);
    $("#info").attr("hidden", false);
  }
});
```

```css
#menu, #info {
  top:0;
  left:0;
  min-height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>

<a href="javascript://" class="button_do">Кнопка для закрытия и открытия блоков</a>

<div id="menu" hidden>
  <ul>Меню</ul>
</div>

<div id="info">
  <p>инфа </p>
</div>
```

P.S. Разное расположение элементов, т.к. у объекта #menu браузером по умолчанию заданы стили: `-webkit-padding-start: 40px;`

Comment: Не красиво копировать скрипт с чужого ответа

Comment: мне кажется, это Вы у меня взяли, забыв добавить ещё стили

Comment: правда? 2 блока на хтмл? а их по другому и не напишешь, а вот по истории изменений видно кто у кого что взял

Comment: далеко пойдете, удачи

Comment: Вы лучше скажите, [что вот это такое](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_ul.asp) "<ul>Меню</ul>"

Comment: это нумерованный список: http://htmlbook.ru/html/ul